# Derivation of expected value of $\exp(-aX^2)$ when $X$ is normally distributed

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, laplace-transform, chi-squared

I am trying to derive the following result:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-aX^{2}\right)\right],$$ such that
$$X\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\sigma^{2}\right),$$ 
$$a = a_{R} + ia_{I},$$
$$a_{R},a_{I} \in \mathbb{R},$$
$$i=\sqrt{-1}.$$

I'm aware that the solution to this is

$$\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{\mu^{2}a}{2a\sigma^2+1}\right)}{\sqrt{2a\sigma^2+1}},$$

but I am having a devil of a time arriving at this solution. It's clear to me that the expression will have to be manipulated to somehow such that one obtains the Laplace Transform of the Chi-Squared Distribution (one degree of freedom) PDF scaled by a constant, but it's really not clear to me how to get there.

Would anyone please be so kind to give me a hand here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: You want to calculate the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} e^{-ax^2}\, dx.$$ To do this, try and combine the exponentials and *complete the square* in the exponent. Eventually you will make use of the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha u^2}\, du = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\alpha}}$ for $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: It may help you to notice that by basic complex analysis it is enough to prove the formula when $a$ is a positive real number. @pmms 12585

Comment: @minus-one-twelfth Thank you so much! I tried completing the square earlier, but I was approaching it from the wrong perspective. And of course I totally forgot to consider going back to the polar coordinates trick. ;)